# Repeatedly creating new Vec vs reusing a mutable Vec

Tags: rust

I recently started working on a new Rust project which requires a lot of attention to performance stats. We are processing millions of rows and there is a code path that creates a small `Vec` for each row. I wanted to see whether it makes sense to have a mutable `Vec` instead of creating a new `Vec` for each row, so I did this test:

```
fn main() {
    understand_create_vec_cost();
    understand_mut_vec_cost();
}

fn understand_mut_vec_cost() {
    let timer = std::time::Instant::now();
    let mut v1 = Vec::<(usize, usize, usize, usize)>::new();
    let mut v2 = Vec::<(usize, usize, usize, usize)>::new();
    for _ in 0..100000000 {
        let random_val1 = rand::random::<usize>();
        let random_val2 = rand::random::<usize>();
        v1.clear();
        v1.push((random_val1, random_val2, random_val1, random_val2));
        v1.push((random_val2, random_val1, random_val2, random_val1));

        v2.clear();
        v2.push((random_val2, random_val1, random_val2, random_val1));
        v2.push((random_val1, random_val2, random_val1, random_val2));

        if v1.len() != 2 && v1[0].0 != random_val1 {
            println!("v1 is empty");
        }
        if v2.len() != 2 && v2[0].0 != random_val2 {
            println!("v2 is empty");
        }
    }
    println!("Mut Vec: Completed in {:?}", timer.elapsed().as_millis());
}

fn understand_create_vec_cost() {
    let timer = std::time::Instant::now();
    for _ in 0..100000000 {
        let random_val1 = rand::random::<usize>();
        let random_val2 = rand::random::<usize>();
        let v1 = vec![
            (random_val1, random_val2, random_val1, random_val2),
            (random_val2, random_val1, random_val2, random_val1),
        ];
        let v2 = vec![
            (random_val2, random_val1, random_val2, random_val1),
            (random_val1, random_val2, random_val1, random_val2),
        ];

        if v1.len() != 2 && v1[0].0 != random_val1 {
            println!("v1 is empty");
        }
        if v2.len() != 2 && v2[0].0 != random_val2 {
            println!("v2 is empty");
        }
    }
    println!("New Vec: Completed in {:?}", timer.elapsed().as_millis());
}
```

The results always showed that **mutable** version is around half a second **slower**. Below is a sample result, but all were mostly similar. These were measured using **release** build.

- New Vec: Completed in 1187 ms.
- Mut Vec: Completed in 1568 ms.

So my questions are

1. Does this code make sense for the purpose? Are there any compiler optimizations that happen under the hood because the code was simple? (I added those if conditions thinking that might avoid any compiler optimizations that might favor one implementation)
2. Do these results make sense? And why is that? Naive me thinks that each `Vec` creation means a lot of allocations, and that should cost more than calling `clear` on the mutable vector.
3. I don't have industrial experience in Assembly/C++. What is the right way to start learning about performance-based coding in Rust? What are some starting points?

Comment: It seems like the allocations are being completely optimized out in the "create" version. I replaced the call to `random()` with a local value that's incremented on every iteration. Before: 1600ms/2100ms; After: 0ms/500ms.

Comment: Update: I wrapped the `vec![]` call with `std::hint::black_box` (available in nightly only) to try to force the allocation and now the create version runs in 12 seconds vs 2 seconds for the mutating one.

Answer (score 2):

The flaw in your test lies in the way the `vec!` macro is constructed. when called with arguments, it pre-allocates the space the arguments take in memory immediately. As a hobbyist Rustacean, I would personally recommend using the new vectors so the data can still be borrowed again, since you'll be doing lots of borrowing in rust, but if you have a use case for a mutable vector, (would test myself, but have potato computer) try running it again with `let mut let mut v1 = Vec::<usize,usize,usize,usize>::with_capacity(2);` which will preallocate the space of two `(usize,usize,usize,usize)` tuples on the stack. By the way, if you want performance and are using the same sized thing every time with the same type (as in the example) you'll be best off using a fixed-size array- declared like `[usize;4]`, i.e `let v1 = Vec::<[usize;4]>::with_capacity(2);` which will instead store it on the stack, making your memory much safer and your program much faster since the computer doesn't have to go searching for data.

Forgive me if you were already aware of this resource, but if you are new to rust I reccomend [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/) for quickly grasping the basics of rust in a manner oriented towards devs moving from other languages (like `C`)

Comment: Not sure why are you speaking about stack here. `Vec` always stores its data at heap, no matter what's the type or initial capacity.

Comment: In my case, number of entries are not known until the last moment. It is a small number though. So that make it impossible to use the `with_capacity` that is why I did not use it for this test.

Comment: @Esdeseserdt1976, You are right. It is the `vec` macro that does the magic. I replaced it with two push calls, then the new Vector creation method took more than 8s.

Comment: @Cerberus thanks for the pointer on the "vec allocate to stack" mistake, but I stand by what I say about storing the values in an array instead ofa tuple. Storing as a tuple, the vec stores pointers to heap data of the tuples, while storing an array causes storage of pointers to the stack, which is faster

Comment: @Esdeseserdt1976 that is not correct either, there's no meaningful difference between `(usize, usize, usize, usize)` and `[usize; 4]` here. You would need a reference type for the vector elements to refer to something on the stack.

Comment: Storing either a tuple or the array doesn't store any pointers. This is not Java, where everything is a reference - in Rust, these things are explicit, and by default everything is stored right where it's written.